# Is there an algorithm to find the most factorizable integer around some specified value?

Tags: algorithms, factoring, prime-factorization, integers

Say I have a number (n=337,023) and a maximal distance (d=1,012). Is there an algorithm that would find the number k in the interval between n-d and n+d  with the largest number of divisors that is more efficient than simply computing all the factors of all the numbers in the interval?

**Added:** The question is out of pure curiosity. I had to choose the size of a picture in pixels with some vague constraint (like "width around 700") and was thinking that finding a number that could be divided by a lot of numbers might be more convenient (so that I could partition the image into smaller parts). Then I found myself trying to find nicely divisible numbers around my constraints. I asked quickly google for a way of finding them but without success.
(In that particular case an approximate solution was sufficient, or even just a multiple of 12 or 60 or whatever.)

Comment: Numbers with many divisors/factors are often called *smooth* numbers.

Comment: If you take the logarithm of $n-d$ and $n+d$ and the logarithm of prime factors this becomes a variant of the knapsack problem. How can I add the logs of the prime factors together to get the most factors and fit into the range? The knapsack optimization problem is NP-hard. So there may not be a polynomial time solution to this problem. In which case factoring all the numbers in the interval may be quickest. That said I'm working on an answer that kind of points the way to a method.

Comment: Wouldn't the "value" of each prime factor be one in that interpretation? Then taking a power of two would be sufficient. But this doesn't introduce the constraint of the lower bound.

Comment: It doesn't quite make your prescribed interval, but $332640$ is a [highly composite number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highly_composite_number), having more divisors than any smaller number.

Comment: @TTFarreo:  no, the value of a prime factor depends on the number of factors of that prime already.  Adding a completely new prime doubles the number of factors.  Changing a prime that is already in as a square to a cube multiplies the number of factors by $\frac 43$.  If you look at the factors of the highly composite numbers you can see the tradeoff.  You get lots of powers of $2$, some powers of $3$, etc.  then add a new large prime

Answer (score 1):

For your purpose, I would just store the list of highly composite numbers, [OEIS A002182](https://oeis.org/A002182) and find the largest one that divides a number in your range.  The example you gave allows numbers from $336,011$ to $338,035$.  We can note that $3 \cdot 110,880=332,640$, which is not so far outside your range and has $192$ factors.  You could search downward in the list until you find one with a multiple in your range, or you could say that your range is $2024$ so take the largest one less than that so your are guaranteed a multiple and find $201 \cdot 1680 = 337,680$ which has $120$ factors.  Just outside your range is $200 \cdot 1680=336,000$ with $128$ factors.  This is really an enhancement of choosing a multiple of $60$ and calling it a day, which is not unreasonable.

Comment: I may not have mentioned this, Guy Robin gave a method in his dissertation for quickly finding the highly composite numbers between two consecutive superior highly composite numbers. http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~nicolas/hcnrevisited.pdf

Comment: hymmm. on page 232. Nicolas says reference [60] while the dissertation is [61]. Robin was his student. https://www.genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=65866  The simplest of their effective upper bounds, bottom of page 229, was published in [43]

Comment: Indeed that's a very simple method. It doesn't fit the constraint though in terms of an "abstract" problem assuming no flexibility on the interval.

Comment: @WillJagy The Nicholas paper is interesting, but it's not clear how to apply it to finding the $n$ which maximize $d(n)$ in an interval. In the OP's interval $[336011, 338035]$, the 6 numbers with highest divisor counts (sorted descending on $d(n)$ & ascending on $n$) are *not* hcn: $$\begin{array}{}336600&144&2^3\cdot3^2\cdot5^2\cdot11\cdot17\\336960&140&2^6\cdot3^4\cdot5\cdot13\\336336&120&2^4\cdot3\cdot7^2\cdot11\cdot13\\337680&120&2^4\cdot3^2\cdot5\cdot7\cdot67\\336168&96&2^3\cdot3^2\cdot7\cdot23\cdot29\\336420&96&2^2\cdot3^3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot89\\\end{array}$$

Comment: @PM2Ring good to know.